# Stopping execution of an included php file...from a class function

Tags: php

I'm trying to devise a plugin system for a simple web app I'm developing.

Each plugin begins with the function call register_plugin that contains that plugins info, like name, description, etc.

I want to be able to set a mode, say, to 1, and then have the ability to include the plugin file, have it call the register_plugin, and then EXIT the included script only. I know that I can stop execution with a simple `return;`, however, the register_plugin function is located in a different file, a class, so I can't simply call return because that will only end the function.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps provide some examples of your included file and the calling scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have outlined in your question, you would need to change the structure of your code and files to get this to work.

There is no magic kind of `return` that would not leave the function but the file or that would leave the function, then the file.

You need to re-arrange your code, add additional checks then to provide the functionality you're looking for.